# Java - changing pointers changing values?

Tags: java, arrays, pointers

I have an array in Java that is filled with data.
What I want to know is, if I do something like this:

```
int[] array = new int[2];
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 1;

//other statements...

array[1] = array[0];
```

and if I change the value of `array[1]` again, will the value of `array[0]` change as well?
Thanks!

Comment: No, because ints are primitives, not pointers to objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and if I change the value of array[1] again, will the value of array[0] change as well?

No. This statement:

```
array[1] = array[0];
```

*Just* copies the value of the second element into the first element. It's just as if you had two separate variables:

```
int x = 10;
int y = x;
// Further changes to x don't affect y
```

The same is *also* true - but more subtly - if you have an array of references, e.g.

```
StringBuilder[] builders = new StringBuilder[10];
builders[0] = new StringBuilder("Original");
builders[1] = builders[0];
builders[0] = new StringBuilder("Hello");
System.out.println(builders[1]); // Prints Original
```

The last assignment statement *doesn't* change the value of `builders[1]`... but if instead we'd written:

```
builders[0].append("Foo");
System.out.println(builders[1]); // Prints OriginalFoo
```

then the values of `builders[0]` and `builders[1]` haven't changed - they still refer to the same object - but the contents of *that object* have changed, hence the output in the final line.